# Unable to setup Einstein Bot in my enterprise edition

Tags: lightning, liveagent, einstein, chat, bots

I have a enterprise edition with required licences for Einstein bots but I can't see the "Einstein bots" in the setup.

In the [documentation](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/service_bots_basics/enable-einstein-bots), it says I need the "Service Cloud" license and the "Chat license"

These are licences I have:

. User Licenses:

- Analytics Cloud Integration User
- Chatter External
- Chatter Free
- Chatter Only
- Company Communities
- Customer Community
- Customer Community Login
- Customer Community Plus  Active
- Customer Community Plus Login
- External Identity
- High Volume Customer Portal
- Partner Community
- Partner Community Login
- Salesforce
- Salesforce Platform
- Work.com Only

. Feature Licenses:

- Marketing User
- Offline User
- Knowledge User
- Salesforce CRM Content User
- Flow User
- **Service Cloud User**
- Data.com User
- Site.com Publisher User
- Chatter Answers User
- **Chat User**
- Work.com User
- Site.com Contributor User

I have the chat license and the Service Cloud license.
What is wrong please?
Have I wrong licenses?

Regards

Comment: Are you in lightning?  Have you tried the steps to launch the guided setup?  > Run the Chat guided setup flow.

This flow is available from Service Setup in Lightning Experience. If your org has Service Cloud, you can get to Service Setup by clicking ￼ and selecting Service Setup.

Comment: Yes, I am in lightning and I have the Service Setup but where can I run the chat guided setup flow?

Comment: I don't have a license so am just reading from the docs, but it says the following, maybe that helps?  >> In Service Setup, you can find recommended setup flows, content, and tips based on what you’ve set up already. If you don’t see the setup flow you’re looking for, you can click View All to see the full list.

Comment: I created a case on Salesforce and they told me I don't have licenses so I have a to submit an order form supplement.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323394&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1